# Place an image on div, that resizes with it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a login page, with a form for a username and password. Sometimes I'll need to place an image on top of the login form, that resizes with said login form on smaller devices. 
Here's the login form today

[image: image no extra]

And with an image attached (just took one, this is not how I envision it :) )
[image: imagewith extra]

I imagine that i'll need some js to find the current placement and size of the form box, and then resize accordingly?

The reason I can't just resize it manually, is that there will be multiple different login pages, and I'll need to make it very easy to create a new context. The size and placement of the image will always be the same

```
<div class="valign-wrapper" style="width:100%;height:100%;position: absolute;">
<div class="valign" style="width:100%;">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 offset-m3">
      <div class="card hoverable">
        <div class="card-image">
          <div class="la-logo"></div>
          <!--<span class="card-title">Login</span>-->
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <!--<span class="card-title black-text">Sign In <i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>-->
          <form name="login" id="login" class="login" method="POST" action="j_security_check" target="_top">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input placeholder="Username" autocapitalize="none" id="username" type="text" class="validate" name="j_username" />
                <!--<label for="firstname" class="active">First Name</label>-->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12 ">
                <input placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password" class="validate" name="j_password" />
                <!--<label for="lastname" class="active">Last Name</label>-->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="center-btn">
                <input type="submit" class="la-largebtn btn hide-on-med-and-down" value="Log In" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn hide-on-large-only" value="Log In" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">

          <div class="center-btn la-hideable">
            <a class="la-register" href="#">Register</a>
            <a class="la-forgot-password" href="#">Forgot Pasword</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to make sure: The penguin should scale down proportionally with the formbox, and remain in place
I'm using sass, and can easily implement js or jquery or whatever makes this the easiest

Comment: This can be done purely with CSS.  Have you tried anything at all yet?  If so, post it please.

Answer (score 2):

You could just define the size of the image relatively to the size of the container (while the image is inside of the container) and then shift it out of the container according to your desire. For example:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>

div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ff0000;
  position: relative;
}
div img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  right: -20%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pLrdtgsg/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "vh/vw" as image size so that it will update itself based on screen height or width respectively.

For example:

```
img{
height: 10vh;
width: 20vw;
}
```